# MongoDB Returns Empty Error Object when Making POST Request

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, postman

I'm currently learning about APIs. I'm using [Dev Ed's video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vjf774RKrLc) on a RESTful MERN API. I set up my routes and I could successfully connect to my MongoDB database. However, when attempting to call `save()` on a post to the DB, I was returned my error message, a JSON object with a message containing the `err`, but my `err` object was completely empty.

**posts.js:**

```js
const express = require('express'); 
const router = express.Router(); 
const Post = require('../models/Post'); 

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('We are on /posts!'); 
}); 

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    const post = new Post({
        title: req.body.title, 
        desc: req.body.desc, 
    }); 

    post.save()
    .then(data => {
        res.json(data); 
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.json({ message: err }); 
    });
}); 

module.exports = router;
```

**app.js:**

```js
const express = require('express'); 
const mongoose = require('mongoose'); 
const bodyParser = require('body-parser'); 

require('dotenv/config'); 

const app = express(); 
const PORT = 8080; 


app.use(bodyParser.json()); 

// Import Routes ------------------------ 
const postsRoute = require('./routes/posts'); 
app.use('/posts', postsRoute); 

// ROUTES --------------------------------
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('We are home!'); 
}); 


mongoose.connect(
    process.env.DB_CONN, 
    { useNewUrlParser: true }, 
    () => {
    console.log('Succesfully connected to DB!')
}); 

app.listen(PORT);
```

**Post.js (schema):**

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose'); 

const PostSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String, 
        required: true, 
    }, 
    desc: {
        type: String, 
        required: true, 
    }, 
    date: {
        type: Date, 
        default: Date.now, 
    }
}); 

module.exports = mongoose.model('Posts', PostSchema);
```

**My POST request and response (Postman):**
[image: image of my POST request and the response (Postman).]

In my code, I am attempting to send the `new Post` to my DB, but instead I get an error, an empty one. I either need to figure out how to view my error correctly (so that's it's not empty) or the larger problem: why my POST request is failing.

Again, I am learning about APIs, this is my very first time writing one. If there's anything I missed (like other code that you would need) or if there's something I should be doing differently, please, let me know! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use status when you want to use res like this:

for success result

```
res.status(200).json(data);
```

for `.catch`

```
res.status(500).json({ message: err });
```

but I prefer use `async/await` with `try/cacth` like this:

```
router.post('/', async(req, res) => {
    const post = new Post({
        title: req.body.title, 
        desc: req.body.desc, 
    }); 
    try {
        let data = await post.save()
        res.status(200).json(data)
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: error}); 
    }
});
```

check the [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html) of promises in mongnoos

check the connection of mongoose like this:

```
const express = require('express'); 
const mongoose = require('mongoose'); 
const bodyParser = require('body-parser'); 

require('dotenv/config'); 

const app = express(); 
const PORT = 8080; 


app.use(bodyParser.json()); 

// Import Routes ------------------------ 
const postsRoute = require('./routes/posts'); 
app.use('/posts', postsRoute); 

// ROUTES --------------------------------
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('We are home!'); 
}); 

runMongoose()

app.listen(PORT); 


async function runMongoose(){
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(
      process.env.DB_CONN, 
      { useNewUrlParser: true }
  ); 
    console.log("mongodb is OK");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("mongodb Warning", error);
  }
}
```

if `Succesfully connected to DB!` printed mongoose connection is OK

Comment: Okay, thank you, I did this. I heard Dev Ed talking about this in his video, but he was trying to keep the tutorial simple. Thank you, though. Got any idea why it's not working though?

Comment: Yes, I will try your async/await method, as exec() returns an error and Node shuts down the server!

Comment: in async/await method set a console.log(error) in the catch befor res.status() and show me the error?

Comment: Okay, using the promise method, I'm getting "TypeError: post.save(...).exec is not a function" and using try...catch I get a "timed out after 10000ms" error. Could it be because my DB is being hosted in northern US and I'm in southern US (takes too long)?

Comment: exec with save is incorrect answer and I deleted, but check the connection of mongoose, do use mongodb localy?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean (still very new to this), but since MLabs has recently moved to their parent company MongoDB I had to figure out how to use that. I'm using "MongoDB native drivers" (the URI thing) to connect. My log message for connecting to the DB does show every time I run my code.

Comment: Okay, I copy/pasted your function. I was returned the warning message! ("mongodb Warning MongoParseError: URI does not have hostname, domain name and tld").

Comment: you cannot connect to the database, because the url is incorrect , check the url

Comment: you can use mongodb atlas like this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rPqRyYJmx2g, I don't know where is your database and I want to connect to its

Comment: Yes!! Thank you so much! I updated my URI with a new password and it works now! I must've had something typed in wrong. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes of course, sorry I got side-tracked writing the API yesterday (very excited)! I finished the API, so now I'm starting another 1-hour video on a registry/login auth page. Thanks again for all of your help! (please upvote my question, thank you) :)

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you added

```
{ useNewUrlParser: true }
```

remove that and it's gonna work fine ;)